# How to change mask color from white to other color?

Tags: python, opencv, mask

I would to change mask color from white to other color, such as red color.

I have tried:

```
image1 = cv2.imread('image1.png',0)
light_color = 100
dark_color = 200
mask_1 = cv2.inRange(image1, light_color, dark_color)
cv2.imshow('mask_1', mask_1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code gave white mask. How can I change the code to give a red mask?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `inRange` returns a monochrome/grayscale result -- 0 (black) or 255 (white).  You can change it to an RGB result and multiply by your desired color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`cv2.inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981) returns a **single channel** image with values that are either 0 or 255.

In order to change it to an image with red pixels where the original mask was 255, you can use [`cv2.cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) to convert to **3 channels** (BGR is opencv's default), and then numpy's [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to change the white pixels to e.g. red (or any other color):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# ...

mask_1_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(mask_1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
mask_1_bgr[np.where((mask_1_bgr==[255, 255, 255]).all(axis=2))] = (0, 0, 255)    
cv2.imshow('mask_1_bgr', mask_1_bgr)
```

You can also do this by using the original mask again for the color change (without `np.where`):

```
import cv2

# ...

mask_1_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(mask_1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
mask_1_bgr[mask_1==255] = (0,0,255)
cv2.imshow('mask_1_bgr', mask_1_bgr)
```

**Note** that since the image is BGR, red is represented by (0, 0, 255).